# Styles apply improperly to an audio element when viewed on mobile

Tags: html, css, audio, html5-audio

Here is how the player should look like, the text and the play icon invert colors beneath them, so they are still visible. This works on PC:

[image]

However, on mobile browser (Safari) text inversion works, but the play button stays white so it's not visible when the progress bar passes through it:

[image]

Here is CSS for my player:

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#audioshadow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

#audioshadow img {
  max-height: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: none;
}

#audiodiv:hover ~ #audioshadow img {
  display: initial;
}

#volume-slider-container {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* COLOR OVERLAY */
#color-switch {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 608px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

#color-switch img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* BUTTONS */
button {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

#play-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 1;
  filter: invert(1);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: transparent;
}

path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  object-fit: cover;
}

button.navigation-button-info {
  margin-top: 0;
}

button.navigation-button-nwsletter {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#mute-icon {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background: transparent;
}

/* WRAPS */
#player {
  --seek-before-width: 0%;
  --volume-before-width: 100%;
  --buffered-width: 0%;
  max-height: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 608px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  user-select: none;
}

#audio-player-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
  /* background color */
  background-color: #000;
}

#volume-slider-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: -30px;
  max-width: 608px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  content-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#player:hover #volume-slider-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

#volume-slider {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scaleY(5.5);
}

#volume-slider-squish {
  position: relative;
}

#volume-slider-squish::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  width: var(--volume-before-width, 0);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#audio-player-container::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

/* OUTPUTS + TEXT */
.time {
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

#duration {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#current-time {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

output {
  width: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

/* SLIDERS */
input[type="range"] {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: default;
  /* COLOR AFTER */
  background-color: #000;
}

input[type="range"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  width: var(--seek-before-width);
  height: 32px;
  /* COLOR BEFORE */
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: black;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: white;
  height: 32px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: default;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-ms-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

#volume-slider {
  float: left;
}

#volume-slider-squish {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  float: left;
  /*   background-color: blue; */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#volume-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider::-moz-range-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider::before {
  width: var(--volume-before-width);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"] {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"] {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::before {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-moz-focus-outer {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 4px;
}

#volume-slider-squish>input[type="range"]:active::-ms-thumb {
  height: 4px;
}
```

And here is HTML for it:

```
<!-- PLAYER -->
<div id="player">
<!-- CHANGE PLAYER COLOR -->
<div id="color-switch"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/SYyiJUa.png">

<div id="volume-slider-container">
<output id="volume-output">100</output>
<div id="volume-slider-squish">
<input type="range" id="volume-slider" max="100" value="70">
</div>
<button id="mute-icon"></button>
</div>

<div id="audio-player-container">
<audio src="https://assets.codepen.io/4358584/Anitek_-_Komorebi.mp3" preload="metadata" loop></audio>

<button id="play-icon"></button>
<span id="current-time" class="time">0:00</span>
<input type="range" id="seek-slider" max="100" value="0">
<span id="duration" class="time">0:00</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```